# Is there a better way to set the selected item in a drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have built an edit page that contains an HTML 5 `select` list and the only way I can figure out to mark the correct item as `selected` based off the data in the model is an if statement. I was just wondering if there was a better way, for my small list it is not much but for larger lists there has to be a better way.

Controller:

```
    [Route("Edit")]
    public ActionResult EditSection(Int16 id = -1)
    {
        Section section = db.Sections.Find(id);
        if (section == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(section);
    }
```

View:

```
    @Html.Label("Type", "Section Type:")
    <select id="Type" name="Type">
        <option value="Game" @if (Model.Type == "Game") { <text> selected="selected" </text> }>Game</option>
        <option value="Collection" @if (Model.Type == "Collection") { <text> selected="selected" </text>  }>Collection</option>
        <option value="Cinema" @if (Model.Type == "Cinema") { <text> selected="selected" </text>  }>Cinema</option>
        <option value="Book" @if (Model.Type == "Book") { <text> selected="selected" </text>  }>Book</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Why did you hardcode the optionsvalues? I assume your sectionstable contain this?

Comment: They are hardcoded because they are not contained in the DB

Comment: There you got your problem. if you REALLY have to hardcode them, then do it in the controller instead of the view. then you make a foreach loop and if model.type == value in hardcoded list then selected:)

Comment: The options never change and I don't see the advantage of creating a table to hold 3 values and make an extra DB pull just for them. I had thought about building it in the controller but I can not find a way to build it in the controller and pass it up to the view since I am already passing up the model.

Comment: i Have added simple way to make your code work, but i would still recommend a viewmodel as Shyju shows you :)

Comment: Thanks to both you for the options. I think I will be taking Shyju's approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a viewmodel which has a collection property to hold your dropdown items.

```
public class SectionEditViewModel
{
  public Section Section { set;get;}
  public List<SelectListeItem> Types { set;get;}
  public string SelectedType { set;get;}

  public SectionEditViewModel()
  {
    Section=new Section();
    Types=new List<SelectListItem>();        
  }
}
```

In your action method, Create an object of this view model, set the property values and send that to the view.

```
public ActionResult EditSection(Int16 id = -1)
{
    Section section = db.Sections.Find(id);
    if (section != null)
    {
       var vm=new SectionEditViewModel { Section=section};
       vm.Types=GetTypes(); 
       vm.SelectedType=section.Type;
       return View(vm);
    }
    return View("NotFound");        
}
```

Assuming `GetTypes` method will return a collection of `SelectListItem`

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetTypes()
{
  var list=new List<SelectListItem>();
  list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="Books", Text="Books"});
  list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="Movies", Text="Movies"});
  list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="Games", Text="Games"});
  return list;
}
```

and in your view which is strongly typed to our `SectionEditViewModel`,

```
@model SectionEditViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{     
  <label>Type :</label>  @Html.DropdownListFor(s=>s.SelectedType,Model.Types)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

When the form is posted, You can read the `SelectedType` Property value and save it

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditSection(SectionEditViewModel model)
{
 //check model.SelectedType 
 //to do : Save and redirect;
}
```

Comment: I have gotten this working with one small change, for the DropDownList declaration was updated to `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedType, new SelectList(Model.Types, "Text", "Value"))`

Answer (score 1):

In The Controller

```
var ListOfTypes = new List<string>(){
     "Game",
     "Collection"
     //etc
}

ViewBag.ListOfValues = ListOfTypes;
```

In The View

```
<select id="Type" name="Type">
@foreach(string type in ViewBag.ListOfValues )
{
     @if(type == Model.Type)
            <option value="@type" selected="selected">@type</option>
     else
            <option value="@type">@type</option>

}
</select>
```